# Change language inside the app using Picker view

Tags: ios, swift

My task is to change the language settings from English to two other languages. I added those languages in the Localization and creates Localizable string file where I added those three languages, however, I don't know how to apply this changes. I need to pick a language from a picker, press "save" and apply those changes. Also I have a button "Reset" which will turn the app back to English. I would like to see the exact code of how to apply it< if possible, please[image]

Comment: https://github.com/shomi11/In-App-LanguageChange, you have a complete code here with all reloading stuff, i have something like that before, it is not picker but you can just fire func there and result will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to simply set the `language` key in the `UserDefaults` to alter the language of the app. Although, the views will have to be reloaded to apply these changes to the strings that are already being loaded.

Here's a working example that you can use:

```
enum Language: String, CaseIterable {
    case english, german, french

    var code: String {
        switch self {
        case .english: return "en"
        case .german: return "de"
        case .french: return "fr"
        }
    }

    static var selected: Language {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set([newValue.code], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "language")
        }
        get {
            Language(rawValue: UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "language") ?? "") ?? .english
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Language.selected = .french
```

You can modify the above API according to your needs.